# Problems sending an Enter key press to an external application with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

I am trying to send an Enter key press to an external application with the following code. I've done a lot of research on this topic in WPF but have yet to get it to work. Can anyone see why this may not be working?

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
    const int VK_ENTER = 0x0D;

    SendMessage((IntPtr)myProcess.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)VK_ENTER, IntPtr.Zero);
    SendMessage((IntPtr)myProcess.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, (IntPtr)VK_ENTER, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Note:

-I don't have any access to the external application's code as it is not mine.

-SendKeys will not work in WPF.

Comment: well I don't know wpf but I think you need to implement a receive message method to other app but as it is not yours, you cannot... I wonder if this have a solution

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with WPF at all, does the code work if you invoke it within a WinForms Application or why do you explicit mention WPF. If it does not work in WinForms either, can you please remove the tag / and title.

Comment: Do you lunch the application as Admin? If not try to do so

Comment: I added WPF in the tags because when I don't specifically mention WPF i often get answers that can only be implemented in other programs like WinForms. A perfect example of this is SendKeys.

Comment: Faking input through `SendMessage` is unreliable for a number of reasons. If you need to automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) instead.

Comment: Do you know where I could find an applicable example of using UI Automation? My search efforts are failing me. @IInspectable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this from a Win32 application or something other than WPF and it works?  You need an understanding of the external application itself in order to try and speak to it.  You're sending an enter message to the window, but is anything focused on the external application, does it need to be activated to process the event, is the external application purposely blocking/filtering out external commands?  There are many things that could be happening.

One thing you could do to see if sending the message is actually working is debugging two apps.  Try to send a message to another basic application which hits a break point when the it gets a enter pressed command.  If this works, then you know your understanding of the external application in subject is doing something you're not expecting.

The other useful thing about `SendMessage` is that it returns an `int`.  What is the return value after you send the message?  You've probably read it, but make sure you have an understanding of [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx), especially:

> Message sending is subject to UIPI. The thread of a process can send messages only to message queues of threads in processes of lesser or equal integrity level.

and the entire **Remarks** section.  I think its also worthy to understand marshalling [`WM_USER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx), [`WM_APP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644930(v=vs.85).aspx) and [**`RegisterWindowMessage`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947(v=vs.85).aspx)

Let us know what your return value is, if not 0.

### Edit

I googled your question and navigated to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433151/how-to-send-an-enter-key-press-to-another-application), but its tagged `delphi`.  You should be able to try the same [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`PostThreadMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx) call since it is also in `user32.dll`.  The last and second last post [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/635992-c-api-sendmessage-postmessage-replace-sendkeys-help-needed) seem to warn OP to remember to call `KeyUp` any time you send `KeyDown`.  Remember to check return values.

Comment: The return value is 0, but I will look into your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Check your SendMessage call. The first parameter as stated in the msdn document :

```
hWnd [in]
Type: HWND
A handle to the window whose window procedure will receive the message
...
```

is the target application window. Thus with your code you're sending message to your window.

On the other hand in a wpf application "the message loop" acts a little different then the traditional windows applicaions.

I can suggest 2 approaches

1. Download InputSimulator (which is a dll) and try with it.
2. Download InputSimulator (which is a dll). Add a new console application project to your solution, use the InputSimulator in it to send messages and invoke it as a process instance from within your wpf application.